# Как перенести текст из memo в edit?

Tags: delphi

Предположим, что в memo есть некий текст, по нажатию кнопки он должен быть скопирован в edit пробовал так, но ничего не вышло

```
sMemo1.text := sEdit6.text;
```

Просто ничего не появляется в edit и всё.... что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2):

Читать до просветления про работу оператора присваивания :=

а так же про разницу между мемо и едитом

если совсем плохо, но надо, можно сделать так

```
sEdit6.Text := sMemo1.Lines.CommaText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sMemo1.lines.text := sEdit6.text
```

Comment: неа, не получается в обоих случаях

Answer (score 0):

В Edit можно записать только 255 символов, скорее всего, поэтому и не получается. Копировать надо какую-то определённую строку:

```
Edit1.Text:=Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];
```

,где i - индекс копируемой строки, и при копировании желательно проверочку делать: превышает ли длина строки 255 символов (если вертикального скролла у Memo нет - свойство ScrollBars=ssVertical), а с вертикальным скроллом - проверка необязательна.

Comment: Это с каких это пор _в Edit можно записать только 255 символов_? Нет у него таких ограничений. И причем здесь наличие вертикального скролла у Memo?

Answer (score 0):

```
sEdit6.text:= sMemo1.Lines.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понял что тебе нужно. Вот оба варианта рабочие

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(Edit1.Text);

Edit1.Text:=Memo1.Text;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Memo1.Lines:=Edit1.Text;
```

Попробуй так.

Comment: >`[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(63): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TStrings' and 'TCaption'`